# How to comment a method returning a copy of this, using JSDoc?

Tags: jsdoc

How to describe, using the JSDoc tags, this **derivate()** return value? I'm looking for a syntax to describe (`@returns`) the object creation, resulting from mixin of the current object AND the provided properties, to improve the autocompletion.

I thought to something like `@returns @mixes (this, properties)` but it isn't a valid syntax, apparently.

```
const obj = {
  /**
   * @param {{
   *   ...properties: *
   * }} [properties]
     * @returns {{}}
     */
  derivate ({ ...properties } = {}) {
    return { ...this, ...properties }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Does the normal JS comments not work? Or is that what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I'm trying to comment the @returns, which is a NEW object, based on this AND properties, to improve the WebStorm autocomplete.

Comment: OK, so you're not trying to *comment out* any line? You're trying to add descriptive comments and don't know how to *describe* the function  you've written?

Comment: Exactly what I mean, by "using JSDoc".

Comment: OK, then unfortunately I think this question is opinion-based (and thus off-topic).

Comment: Why opinion-based? I really need a pure technical solution to describe my function return value, using the JSDoc decorators.
I thought to something like `@returns @mixes (this, properties)` but it isn't a valid syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure how JSDoc works; if you have tried something already and enctounered an error, please add that information to the question. As it is, I voted as "unclear/needs details", as I had really no idea what the question was until this comment discussion. I was under the impression you just couldn't think of a *good* description for your function, but it seems maybe you have one but for some reason JSDoc is telling you it is invalid and not letting you save, which might be enough information for a JSDoc question to be answered (again, I don't know JSDoc).

Comment: Just updated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution (but `tsc` doesn't like it, then still open for a better soltion):

```
/**
 * @typedef Obj
 * @type {Object}
 */

/**
 * @typedef Properties
 * @type {Object}
 */

/**
 * @typedef Return
 * @type {Object}
 * @augments Obj
 * @augments Properties
 */


/**
 * @type {Obj} obj
 */
const obj = {
  /**
   * @param {Properties} [properties]
   * @returns {Return}
   */
  derivate ({ ...properties } = {}) {
    return { ...this, ...properties }
  }
}
```